# I have a list of urls . I run OpenreadAsyn(url1) to OpenReadAsync(urlN) .. How do I wait for all of them to complete

Tags: c#, multithreading, rest, webclient

I have a result list of length N.
I have a URL list of N URLs. 
I need to perform below operation.

```
            List<Result> results=new List<Result>;
            //Urls is a list of URLs.

            public void FillResults()
            {
                 foreach( var urlx in Urls)
                 {
                        GetResponse(urlx, (response) =>
                        {
                            if (response != null && response.StatusCode==200)
                            {
                                Result result=new Result;
                                result.Value=response.SomeValue;
                                result.url=urlx;------>It is important that SomeValue corresponds to urlx and not other say,urly
                                results.Add(result);


                            }
                        });
                }
            }

             //wait till List results is completely filled

             private void GetResponse(Uri uri, Action<MyResponse> callback)
                    {
                        using(var m_webClient = new WebClient())
                        {
                        m_webClient.OpenReadCompleted += (o, a) =>
                        {
                            if (callback != null)
                            {
                                DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(MyResponse));
                                callback(ser.ReadObject(a.Result) MyResponse);

                            }
                        };
                        m_webClient.OpenReadAsync(uri);

                    }
                }

                public class MyResponse:Response
                {
                }
```

// Wait for the results list to be filled completely

I want every request to happen asynchronously which is happening but want to wait untill results list is completely filled to move forward.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use `WebClient` over `HttpClient`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solutions.  The quick and dirty one would be to add a counter to tell how many jobs are remaining that would increase as before call `GetResponse` and decrease within the callback, and if it reaches 0 then call the next step in your process.  This would be risky because of race conditions and unpredictable thread behavior, such as if you call one request and before the second request begins and then it'd try to continue.

The better solution would be to keep track of the Tasks spawned by using `OpenReadTaskAsync` instead of `OpenReadAsync` and then use `Task.WhenAll({ALL YOUR TASKS})`.

It would change your program slightly:

```
List<Result> result = new List<Result>();
List<Task<Stream>> jobs = new List<Task<Stream>>();
```

...

`GetResponse` would have to return a Task value which is straightforward.

```
private Task<Stream> GetResponse(Uri uri, Action<MyResponse> callback)
{
  ... //Almost all of your code stays the same, 
      //though you should close the stream you receive in the OnReadCompleted callback.
  return m_webClient.OpenReadTaskAsync(uri.ToString());
}
```

Last in the `FillResults` method, you have to add these tasks to the list and wait.

```
public async Task FillResults()
{
      foreach( var urlx in Urls)
      {
            jobs.Add(
                      GetResponse(urlx, (response) =>
                      {
                        if (response != null && response.StatusCode==200)
                        {
                            Result result=new Result;
                            result.Value=response.SomeValue;
                            result.url=urlx;------>It is important that SomeValue corresponds to urlx and not other say,urly
                            results.Add(result);
                        }
                      })
                   );
      }

      await Task.WhenAll(jobs);

      //Or Task.WhenAll(jobs).ContinueWith({AN ACTION CALLBACK}) 
      //if you want to keep the return as a void;
}
```

Now you can either await the FillResults function wherever you call that method, or have another callback to handle the finish of

Comment: Thank you . Could you provide code for  private Task<Stream> GetResponse(Uri uri, Action<MyResponse> callback)
{  }

Comment: All the jobs are waiting for activation

Comment: Instead of  WhenAll(jobs) , i wrote   Task.WaitAll(jobs.ToArray()); . This worked . Thanks